# How to search in mysql so that accented character is same as non-accented?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to have:

piščanec = piscanec in mysql. I mean, I'd like to search for piscanec to find piščanec also.

So the č and c would be same, š and s etc...

I know it can be done using regexp, but this is slow :-( Any other way with LIKE? I am also using full text searches a lot.

**UPDATE:**

```
select CONVERT('čšćžđ' USING ascii) as text
```

does not work. Produces: `?????`

Comment: čšćžđ are not ASCII characters, so it makes sense that they are converted into ????? ;)

Comment: Yes, but this was a proposal of one of the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the column with the collation `utf8_generic_ci`. This collation considers š equal to s and č equal to c:

```
create temporary table t (t varchar(100) collate utf8_general_ci);
insert into t set t = 'piščanec';
insert into t set t = 'piscanec';
select * from t where t='piscanec';
+------------+
| t          |
+------------+
| piščanec   |
| piscanec   |
+------------+
```

If you don't want to or can't use the `utf8_generic_ci` collation for the column--maybe you have a unique index on the column and want to consider piščanec and piscanec distinct?--you can use collation in the query only:

```
create temporary table t (t varchar(100) collate utf8_bin);
insert into t set t = 'piščanec';
insert into t set t = 'piscanec';
select * from t where t='piscanec';
+------------+
| t          |
+------------+
| piscanec   |
+------------+
select * from t where t='piscanec' collate utf8_general_ci;
+------------+
| t          |
+------------+
| piščanec   |
| piscanec   |
+------------+
```

The FULLTEXT index is supposed to use the column collation directly; you don't need to define a new collation. Apparently the fulltext index can only be in the column's storage collation, so if you want to use `utf8_general_ci` for searches and `utf8_slovenian_ci` for sorting, you have to use use `collate` in the order by:

```
select * from tab order by col collate utf8_slovenian_ci;
```

Comment: I can not use the general_ci because then all the queries I would get from this field would treat c and č the same which would make sorthing problems like: čebula, česen, cvet. But cvet should be the first as c is before č when sorting.

Comment: If I use the collate utf8_general_ci I do indeed get the results I wanted from a LIKE query. I wonder how much slower this is (have to try) and how it affects the full text search. There I also need to use the collate I guess else piščanec != piscanec.

Comment: Nice thing is that order by still uses out slovenian_ci collate even if I collate the query. Huh.

Comment: Seems for full text search I do not know how to use collate in select :-(

Comment: You can use `utf8_slovenian_ci` for sorting while the column itself is something else: `select * from tab order by col collate utf8_slovenian_ci`

Comment: It works if I put utf8_general_ci on the column and use slovenian_ci for the order by. It does not work if my column has slovenian_ci and I want to match against general_ci. Seems like the column collation is the only relevant thing for full text search. I don't like this because I have to make every order by now in my website have slovenian collation and all the columns to general. In reality the collation should be generally slovenian, just the search should be general_ci so I should just be allowed to use general_ci as collation table in match against, but it DOESN?T work this way :-(

Comment: AH, your last paragraph kind of explains my fears. I have to have the column in general_ci and need to modify all the order by clauses instead. I am not sure if that would make my index work or not if I collate on different collation than the index is stored (normal selects not full text ones I mean here).

Comment: You could add an extra column with 'general' collation and a trigger that makes sure it has the same values as the original, and use the new column for fulltext searches... not optimal but avoids using collate with every order by

Comment: Hm, that is an idea, but then the long text field would be duplicated. And I do not know how to write such trigger. I think maby it is better to stick with order by collation. I think there is no better way although I am not sure about performance impact.

Comment: The trigger is simple, bordering on trivial, but if you don't have enough storage that's ruled out: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,414321,414345#msg-414345 ORDER BY using an explicit collation should not be a lot more expensive than order by the column's own collation because the data will be pretty much sorted already, but you should test it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18240/discussion-between-jerry2-and-joni)

Answer (score 2):

It's not straightforward, but you'll probably best off creating your own collation for your fulltrext searches. Here is an example:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/full-text-adding-collation.html

with more info here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-collation.html

That way, you have your collation logic completely independent of your SQL and business logic, and you're not having to do any heavy-lifting yourself with SQL-workarounds.

**EDIT:** since collations are used for ***all*** string-matching operations, this may not be the best way to go: you will end up obfuscating differences between characters that are linguistically discrete.

If you want to suppress these differences for specific operations, then you might consider writing a function that takes a string and replaces - in a targetted way - characters which, for the purposes of the current operation, are to be considered identical.

You could define one table holding your base characters (š, č etc.) and another holding the equivalences. Then run a REPLACE over your string.

**Another way** is just to `CAST` your string to `ASCII`, thereby suppressing all non-`ASCII` characters.

e.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT('<your text here>' USING ascii) as as_ascii
```

Comment: Thank you. At this second I was just reading that page if it ca help. I thought collation is just for sorting, not for other things, I gues I need to read thru it. Is this collation only for full text searches or for everything on the server that is using this mysql?

Comment: Collation deals with string-matching (and thereby implicitly with sorting), so it should suit your needs. You just implement it once and the database uses it wherever string-matching is required. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Comment: Huh, thank you, it seems complicated to do. I use unicode utf-8 as our charset but we have characters from latin2 8859-2 and from MS1250 (on the keyboard) so uft-8 was the best choice and I have yet to find out if the collation can be changed. Problem is I do not want to affect sortiong, č comes AFTER c, it is not the same, I'd like just the search to find either c and č the saame (mobile phones usually don't have out letters).

Comment: ok, if the logic is not to be universally applied to all string-matching operations, you may have to do it differently.

Comment: Well to all, just not for the sorting as č is different character than c

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do, find a mysql way of telling characters are identical. Regexp has something like [cč] but it is slow.

Comment: You mean one table only special characters and the other only equivalents, not whole ascii table?

Comment: yes, just the equivalents. Although I would probably try the CONVERT first.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18216/discussion-between-davek-and-jerry2)